# How to sort (filter, move, delete) a huge number of files on a NAS

Tags: command-line, file

I have a NAS (Synology ds418), and I access it using my Macbook Pro (macOS 10.15.6)

There is a folder with an unknown amount of files, and I need to classify them:

- delete some files
- filter some files depending on their extensions
- move some files

Unfortunately, it seems there's too many file for my mac to handle.

What I've tried:

1. **Finder**

Using the finder I get the spinning ball of death. It keeps loading but nothing never shows.

2. **Terminal utilities**

Same goes for commands like `find`, `ls`, and other.

3. **Custom program**

I tried to make my own program [as advised here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427032/fast-linux-file-count-for-a-large-number-of-files) But it seems to stop working after a while... (I tried to print the current count to ensure the program is still running and it stops at about 20k)

Nothing works, what else could?

Comment: This isn't a Mac or Synology issue - it's a "too many files in the directory" and possibly a network issue depending on how your accessing things.  You either have to let the utilities work or you need to break the large directory up in to smaller, more manageable "chunks" (subdirs of say no more than 500 files each).

Comment: @Allan Hard to break things apart if you can‘t see them. Running stuff on the Synology will at least take the network part out of the equation and make things easier.

Comment: You don’t really need to see them, to move them.  For example, `mkdir subdir1; i=0; for f in *.* do; while [ i -lt 500 ]; do mv $f subdir1/${f}; ((i++));done;done` will move 500 files into `subdir` reissue the command and increment the `subdir`.  And that’s just quick and dirty for a comment.  But yes, being local to the Synology will definitely help. And you want to test with a smaller number and `cp` before you go to the full `mv` at first!